# Error "Uncaught ReferenceError: desCampos is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo ese fragmento de código y quiero que al apretar el botón "Guardar Datos" el campo "Nombre Del Complejo se me desahabilite y queden los datos guardados dentro de él pero me salta el error "Uncaught ReferenceError: desCampos is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick." Muestro el fragmento de código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form campo" autocomplete="on" (ngSubmit)="guardar(formulario)" #formulario="ngForm">
    <h4 class="title text-center">Complete los datos de su complejo</h4>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-8 row">
      <label class="col-form-label ">Nombre del complejo:</label>
      <input class="form-control campo" type="text" id="campo" ngModel name="nombreComplejo" placeholder="Complejo" required>
    </div>
    <div class="botones">
      <div class="boton">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="formulario.invalid" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btnGuardar" value="Guardar Datos" onClick="desCampos();">Guardar Datos</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>


<script>
  function desCampos() {
    var campo = document.getElementById("campo");
    campo.disabled = true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Tu tag de `<script>` está fuera del `<html>`. Debes colocarlo dentro. Preferiblemente antes del cierre de `</head>`. Esto es porque es una declaración de función y el analizador del navegador lo leerá antes de procesar el cuerpo del documento. Así cuando asigne la función al atributo `onClick`, la función ya estará cargada en memoria. Comenta el resultado.

Comment: Buen día. Gracias por tu tiempo. Eh intentado hacer lo que me dijiste pero así mismo sigue arrojando el error.

Comment: **Corrijo**: eh puesto el código mostrado aquí por separado para ejecutarlo (ya  que el mismo esta acompañado de más codigo. es un formulario) y el error desapareció- Lo que hace ahora, es desactivar el campo y volver a activarlo al instante.